Starting point for pagination query in Power Query
I am pulling from an api that uses these paging parameters (from their website)
`"links": {
    "next": "/api/resource?page[number]=Mw==",
    "prev": null`


my query returns a max 100 rows per page, the next and prev values are like,
next /v1/dept/deptID/projects?page%5Bsize%5D=100&page%5Bnumber%5D=Mg%3D%3D
I have looked at dozens of solutions, and with my limited M skills and can't figure out how to adapt them to my parameters and get links/next url page using next. I am assuming I need to have a baseURL,[next],[Headers=My Auth] to make the next call.
I am hoping to here from someone who has worked with a similar api, been searching for days so if you post a link chances are I have already been there. Thanks for any help.
What I have working right now is a hand-built table of Base64 encoded page numbers, and then I invoke my function on that table, this gets me all the data, but of course I have to know the number of pages. My function,
`Page as text) =>
let
   Source = Json.Document(
       Web.Contents(
           "https://apis-us.MyWeb.com/v1/dept/deptID/sometable",
              [RelativePath = "?page[size]=100&page[number]="&(Page),
                      Headers=[Authorization="Bearer MyToken", #"Content-    Type"="application/vnd.api+json"]])),
    data = Source[data]
in
   data` 


https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Thanks I looked at that one, what my api is returning is very different. What my api uses for paging is a relative/partial path to the next page, like in my post. The api in the gorilla.bi link uses offset for paging which makes using list.generate simple.

"The previous example checked whether the retrieved list had any values in it. An alternative is to use the next column in the record"
